# XSLT 1.0 - Substring a value between other values

Tags: xml, xslt

`<LotId>NOIDEHOB_NOIDE1_4321-123</LotId>`

i want to create a XSLT that extract the value `NOIDE1` from the example above but i cant find a solid way to do it. 
The problem is that `NOIDEHOB` and `4321-123` are dynamic and will change dependig on the xml transaction.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the underscores (_) always going to be located before and after the string you want to extract? Can the parts before and after also contain underscores?

Comment: They underscores will allways be located before and after the string i want to attach. The parts beffore and after will never contain underscores

Comment: Which XSLT processor will you be using? This task is trivial if it supports the EXSLT`str:tokenize()` or `str:split()` extension functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <IdValue>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(LotId,'_'),'_')"/>
    </IdValue>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ehW12fw